# Using IF statement to check if variable contains £ (pounds) sign in PHP

Tags: php

As the title says, I have a variable that I stores data input from the customers, if the data contains a pound sign then that means they entered a pound sign for the price of a product, if doesn't contain a pounds sign, I need to make sure to add it.

I know PHP uses multibyte characters. This is how I'm checking but it's not working:

```
if(($price[0] != "Â") && ($price[1] !="£")){
    $len = strlen($price);
    $char= '£';

    for($t = 0; $t<$len;$t++ ){
        $char .= $price[$t];
    }

    $price = $char;
}
```

How else could I get this working?

Comment: You can use strpos function. check it out here php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: You can use `strpos` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php

Comment: `if (strpos("£", $price) !== false) { /* It's there */ }`

Comment: ok thanks :) will try that

Comment: `str..` functions are bad at mutli-byte strings. Use the the [multi-byte string extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) instead

Comment: @Luke [here's one reason](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6cc26f23f581aa0fb28e0a5eb505be72e2e6c6) in general if you have a character more than one byte long then it's safer to use mbstring because chances are the equivalent `str*` function is assuming an ASCII encoding

Answer (score 0):

Hi use `strpos()` example:

```
$a = '£100';
$b = '100';
if (strpos($a, '£') !== false) {
    echo 'a is price value';
}
if(strpos($b, '£') !== false)
{
    echo 'b is price value';
}
```

May this will work

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)

```
$findme   = '£';
if(strpos($price, $findme)){
  //Pound
}else{
  //No pound
}
```

Comment: `strpos("£100",$findme)` will return 0 which is falsey. You should do `if (strpos($price,$findme) !== false)` to do a strict comparison

Answer (score 0):

You should also try using multi-byte string extensions like mb_strpos instead of strpos